# Which is the best approach to get real time data?

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-8, push-notification, background-process, c#-5.0

I am creating a Windows Phone 8 application in which I need to display real time data like updated coordinate of a second person. Currently the approach that i am using is by creating a timer and making hits to the server every 11 mins.All the data gets updated in the data in real time.

Is there any better way like using Sockets, Push Notification or Background Task to do this if there is can you please elaborate as in how to implement it?

Comment: Please suggest. Waiting for response.

Comment: I think that approach is just fine for your interval.  I suggest you do what the News app does when it can't get any data, which is it display "offline" and shows you what articles was already loaded.  When I think about real time, it's interrupt driven like lets say getting data from an onboard FPGA.

Comment: But don't you think that as number of user increases number of hits to the server after 11 mins increases drastically. I was thinking if some how I can start this process by calling a service and then from there server automatically send me the data as there are updates for all the devices. But the data may differ from device to device. Or may be there is some more optimized approach than using timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Windows Push Notification Services to push notifications to your Windows Phone app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx